# How to copy file from all client to windows server?

Tags: windows, sync

I have 50 local client computer, I wants to take backup(copy) everyday of those client files to one server ex: word,pdf,images etc..

Everyday It has copy file to one server which is connected locally.

I want to maintain 50 folder for 50 client on my server which will have every client files. Those files are copied from client side on everynight

Comment: Look up "Backup software" - Google is your friend.

Comment: @Digitallightcraft I am not talking about that back up. I wants to move the file to another machine or server

Comment: If all 50 client are in same network. Create one folder give the permission to everyone. MAP the folder as Drive let user copy the files into same folder (where its mapped)

Comment: @Liamneesan - there is a LOT of backup software out there, most of it can do exactly what you want.

Comment: @Liamneesan: You should more clear what exactly you want

Comment: @TechieGossip I want to maintain 50 folder for 50 client on my server which will have every client file. those files are should come from client side on everyday basis

Comment: "Those files are should come from client side on everyday basis" I Didnt get this what you told?

Do you have Active Directory for ur clients. How you created all 50 folders? Manually ? how user call the folder which you created?

Comment: Have you managed a network before? @Liamneesan

Comment: Setup remote profiles for those users assuming you have a AD domain; Run a script on login/logoff for each user; run a script every N minutes on every client; run a script every N minutes on the server. You have provided really little detail about what you're trying to accomplish, what your circumstances and requirements are and what you have tried.